# MySQL Query WHERE -> IF

Tags: mysql, if-statement, where-clause

hope someone can help me with this,

im trying to connect a WHERE argument within an MySQL Statement with an IF operation, but i dont know how to handle it...

```
SELECT  k.EventId AS Id
    , ws.Name AS Name
    , dauer AS Dauer
    , kat.Name AS Kurztyp
    , doz.Name AS Dozent        
    , DATE_FORMAT(k.Begin, '%Y-%m-%d') AS Begin
    , COUNT(an.EventId) AS Teilnehmer
FROM kalender AS k
        LEFT JOIN workshop AS ws        
            ON (k.WorkshopId = ws.Id)
        LEFT JOIN angemeldet AS an      
            ON (k.EventId = an.EventId)
        LEFT JOIN dozent AS doz         
            ON (k.Dozent = doz.Id)
        LEFT JOIN ws_kategorie as kat   
            ON ((ws.Kategorie = kat.Id) or (ws.Kategorie2 = kat.Id))
        INNER JOIN bezahlvariante AS bezvar
                ON (an.bezahlvariante_idbezahlvariante = bezvar.idbezahlvariante)
    WHERE kat.Name LIKE '%security%'
        AND k.Begin > '2014-04-01'
        AND k.aktiv = '1'
```

---------------->

```
        AND bezvar.TN_Anzahl_phys = '1'
```

<----------------- this should be like: IF(COUNT(an.EventId)>0) 
                        THAN bezvar.TN_Anzahl_phys = '1'
ELSE bezvar.TN_Anzahl_phys IN (1,2)

```
            GROUP BY k.EventId;
```

How can i use an IF operation like this in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case-when` as

```
GROUP BY k.EventId
having
case 
  when COUNT(an.EventId)>0 then bezvar.TN_Anzahl_phys = '1'
  else
   bezvar.TN_Anzahl_phys IN (1,2)
END
```

Comment: thats correct it will show invalid use of group let ne correct it

Comment: sadly doesnt work, SQL error
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'bezvar.TN_Anzahl_phys' in 'having clause'
idk why

Comment: DDL is way to large, only 8000 allowed but has about 20k? :/

Comment: wow just have some sample data dont need all may be 10 15 rows.

Comment: ouch but usually this kind of syntax should work, try removing the having clause and try to select the col bezvar.TN_Anzahl_phys in select and see if its working. If yes then it should work in the having clause, I just tested in my local mysql using same pattern of query by joining tables and it works well.

Comment: Its not the input data, its the whole MySQL Table-Strukture, i tryed to kick out some none-important rows, but still too long :/

Comment: yep if i put bezvar.TN_Anzahl_phys into select it shows a result ( without the having ) :/ i dont understand why "having" wont find it

Comment: ok just make a selection of that field in the select and the use it on having it should work

Comment: ah ok now it works, but i made a mistake... it returned the wrong result... if count = 0 it should just ignore bezvar.TN_Anzahl_phys ... so i just removed the Else part... but still does not show the results with count = 0

Comment: not sure about the count since its hard to say anything without seeing the data.

Comment: true :/ but nevermind your solution worked, other stuff ill catch within PHP ;) Thank you